# What's the fastest .Net PDF library to dump a bunch of bitmaps to PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I have around 10 `System.Drawing.Bitmap` elements, which I want to dump to PDF. When combining them to a single bitmap, and then writing this to PNG, this takes me about 150 ms.

Now I want to create a PDF out of my bitmaps (4 pages), but with PDFSharp this takes >2.5 seconds. Is there any library that is (way) faster at doing this?

NB. I draw the images on the surface in PDFSharp like:

```
 XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page1);
 gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(/*bitmap*/));
```

*edit* Don't care about paid/free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ITextSharp. Very easy to use and learn.

Comment: +1 and there's a great book on it too which you should get (though there are plenty net based resources too)

Comment: I'm using it for PDF creation in two cases: HTML to PDF and image placing in PDF. So far... rocket fast, i'm totally satisfied with the performance. Generated PDF are > 5 pages.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it (performance-wise or other..), but [aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) has a pdf component which comes with a trial-version.